# how I integrate Azure AD B2C Custom login Policy in my angularjs app?

Tags: angularjs, azure, asp.net-mvc-4, azure-ad-b2c

I create external login page in my mvc app which 
redirect User to custom login page..
and use that external mvc app in my angular js app.
But after login succesfully one should not able to open my angularjs app.
 get Below error.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For implementing Azure AD B2C login with Angular Js application you can refer the GitHub [sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-javascript-angular-spa)